# Настройка nginx. Как сделать его файл-сервером?

Tags: nginx, файлы, header

На сервере есть mp3 Файлы.

Вот строчка в server :

```
location /music/ {
   root /media;
}
```

Но при обращении к файлам нжинкс просто отдает mp3, и большинство современных браузеров пытается его проиграть встроенными средствами. Насколько я знаю, есть специальный заголовок, который заставляет браузер сразу скачать файл.

Как это сделать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Интернет [говорит](https://coderwall.com/p/3yb8vg) мне о таком:

    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$request_basename"';

Хотя мне казалось, что этот заголовок выдается по умолчанию.

Comment: @Etki, я вот не очень разобрался с тем, что там пишут в Location. Если я хочу, чтобы музыка была доступна по урлу <домен>/music, а музыка лежит в /data/music, что мне нужно писать в Location, а что в root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавь в этот location:

```
            default_type    application/octet-stream;
            types           {}
            add_header      Content-Disposition     "attachment";
```

Comment: А есть ли способы вести стастистику по скачиваниям? Записывать количество обращений к урлу или вызывать скрипт при запросе?

Comment: это лучше делать асинхронно отдаче файла. парсите access_log, фильтруя по 200-тому статусу ответа (там еще 206-тые будут)